# UIAlertView delegate inside insertnewObject

Tags: iphone, ios7, uialertview

I am having a uialertview inside the insertnewobject function as shown below.

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //NSLog(@"Hello");
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Reference"
                                                      message:@"Enter Reference Manually"
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Insert Manually"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message addButtonWithTitle:@"Enter ISBN"];
    [message addButtonWithTitle:@"Enter DOI"];
    [message show];
}
```

I can see the UIAlertView. But this function is not being reached at all!!

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Enter ISBN"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Enter DOI"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 2 was selected.");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Insert Manually"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 3 was selected.");
    }
}
```

Kindly let me know where i am going wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set delegate to **self**

Update this line

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Reference"
                                                  message:@"Enter Reference Manually"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Insert Manually"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: Great! If this is the answer you were looking at then Accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead using title proprty, you can use `buttonIndex` property for this directly,And set delegate to self,

Try this

```
 UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Reference"
                                                          message:@"Enter Reference Manually"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Insert Manually"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message addButtonWithTitle:@"Enter ISBN"];
        [message addButtonWithTitle:@"Enter DOI"];
        [message show];
```

Alertview Delegate Method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");

    if(buttonIndex==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");
    }
    else if(buttonIndex==2)
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 2 was selected.");
    }
    else if(buttonIndex==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 3 was selected.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `delegate` nil, the `delegate` should be self to invoke delegated method.

Answer (score 0):

you have set the `delegate:nil` then how it call the delegate methods. just set it to `delegate:self` and see the magic.

```
 UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Reference"
                                                  message:@"Enter Reference Manually"
                                                 delegate:self //just change here 
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Insert Manually"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
```